# Recover data from MySQL Incremental Backup files (.FRM and .IBD files)

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have MySQL Enterprise full and incremental backups (`.FRM` and `.IBD` files).

I have copied the full backup files to a different server, created table structures and imported the data the data using `IMPORT TABLESPACE`.

How do I import the data from the incremental backup files?

Comment: Doesn't MEB come with support from Oracle?

Comment: Hi Viki, Can you provide more details regarding steps have performed ? It would be help to solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Jyoti, I have a Full backup weekly(Sunday) and Incremental backups every 2 hours. on a test server, i have created new schema (TestSchema), created all the tables, executed DISCARD TABLESPACE, copied the .IBD files and executed IMPORT TABLE SPACE. Everything is working fine. Now i need to move the incremental backup data (.IBD files)  to that TestSchema. Please let me know how it can be done.

Comment: That's not the way how MEB works. Try reading this first: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.12/en/restoring.html